# PowerShell Workflow Test-Path throws InformationAction error

Tags: powershell, workflow

Recently we've updated our script server to `PowerShell 5.1`. All other servers are still running `PowerShell 4.0`. Some strange behavior we noticed with `Test-Path` throwing an error within a `PowerShell Workflow`.

**The code:**

```
Workflow Get-Foo {
    Test-Path -Path C:\TEMP
}

Get-Foo -PSComputerName PS4ServerName
```

**The error:**

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'InformationAction'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPat 
   hCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

When running `Get-Foo` locally on the `PowerShell 5.1` machine there is no error. Not even when running it like `Get-Foo -PSComputerName PS51ServerName`.

Why is it complaining about `InformationAction` when we don't even use it?

Comment: PowerShell 4 probably does not have the `InformationAction` variable since it was added in PowerShell 5.

Comment: But we don't use it...

Comment: Might be that the workflow feature takes the default variables from the calling machine and explicitly tries to splat them on the target

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: Would it be too obvious to suggest upgrading the PowerShell 4 machines to PowerShell 5?

Comment: That would be the ideal solution, but we're talking hundreds of machines. I'll try to wrap it in an `InlineScript` clause.

Comment: If you're looking to run a normal PowerShell script multithreaded across multiple computers, Workflows are pretty terrible for that even though, yes, that's what they're ostensibly for.  The design simply doesn't match what people actually want to use them for.  I would try searching for PowerShell and RunspaceFactory.  There will be a number of multithreading scripts that will be much less complicated than setting up a Workflow.